# Image resize script

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation

I'm searching a javascript that can resize images similar to script thats available as a plugin in vBulletin CMS:

[image]

I want the script to be used in blogger blog so that all images i upload into a post are resized to a smaller res and on clicking the image should be displayed in original dimensions

Something of the sort `getelementbyID("img")`.

are there any script providing this feature? Pls help me out

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think what you might want is a server side script (such as PHP) that does the resizing.  If you resize it in javascript, the client still has to download the hi-res image, so it will load slowly for large images.

Comment: @Jeff: It's my understanding it's loaded anyways, they just place the max-extents within a confine. Then, when clicked, it re-sizes it to full extent. Though i suppose it could go both ways, i think caching the "thumbnails" locally of every image posted may be a bit--grueling.

Comment: @Brad If you're talking about vBulletin in particular, I can't say I'm familiar with it.  But resizing in javascript is rather pointless, as cmcculloh points out, when you can just resize using CSS.  If your goal is saving bandwidth and making pages load faster, server-side re-sizing is absolutely the way to go. The image above doesn't look like a thumbnail anyway, it appears to be a moderately sized image that expands to a large image.

Answer (score 1):

Something like a [lightbox](http://fancybox.net/), perhaps?

<sub>I know the specific interaction you're asking about, and personally, I've always found it really obnoxious.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a server side script to automatically create a smaller version of the image that you would link to the larger version, I wouldn't recommend using JavaScript to resize an image either. I'd recommend setting the image's dimensions in CSS and then attaching a click handler with JS that showed the image in some sort of overlay (or just using HTML to link to the larger image file).