# Graph background-image resizing without PHP

Tags: image-processing, background-image, image-resizing

I've read several helpful answers in re. image resizing using PHP and max-height etc.: [Image resize script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314005/image-resize-script)

However, my problem is that I want to resize an image of a graph that I am retrieving from another site (USGS), and putting into a site (zenfolio) that supports HTML and JavaScript, but not PHP. I have tried adjusting the specified height and width, but keep on ending up resizing only the amount of the image that shows on the page, and not the image itself (sorry I cannot post images as I am a new user).

I just posted them as png's above to demonstrate the problem, but the images are generated as follows:

```
<div id="riverlevels"> 
    <center> 
        <div id="MyWidget" style="background-image:url(http://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwisweb/graph?agency_cd=USGS&amp;site_no=12354500&amp;parm_cd=00065&amp;period=21);width:576px;Height:400px;"> 
            <br/> 
            <a href="http://montanariverphoto.com" style="line-height: 3em; font-family:times; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; color:#000033" target="_blank">Montana River Photography </a></div> 
    </center> 
</div>
        </div>
```

This same image can be generated using this JavaScript, but for some reason that does not allow me to display more than one variable graph per page (I want to show both discharge (00060), and gage height (00065)):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
wStation = "12354500";
wDays = "21";
wType = "00065";
wWidth = "576px"; 
wHeight = "400px";
wFColor = "#000033";
wTitle = "";
document.write('<div id="gageheight"></div>');
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/JavaScript"src="http://batpigandme.com/js/showstring.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
```

As you can tell, I have to use a separate site that I own to create the JavaScript file. The graphs are currently located in various iterations at:
[montanariverphoto.com/test](http://www.montanariverphoto.com/test)
[clark fork gage height](http://www.montanariverphoto.com/clark-fork-river-height)

I sincerely apologize if I have missed an obvious answer to this! I basically created this widget by reverse engineering a widget from another site, so perhaps my call is incorrect all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it absolutely have to be a background image? Scaling them is possible (using `background-size`), but this property is not well supported (basically it won't work in Internet Explorer). Your code would work almost as-is if you can use an image tag instead:

```
<img src="http://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwisweb/graph?agency_cd=USGS&amp;site_no=12354500&amp;parm_cd=00065&amp;period=21" width="576" height="400" alt="..." />
```

for your other problem, ids need to be unique on a page. In your code example you are creating a div with the id of `gageheight`, and this is ID is hardcoded into your javascript file at http://batpigandme.com/js/showstring.js. Since you can only have one element with this ID on the page, if you repeat the code later on it won't work. You'd need to change this script so that you could pass in the ID as a variable, something like:

```
wTitle = "";
wElement = "gageheight";
document.write('<div id="gageheight"></div>');
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/JavaScript"src="http://batpigandme.com/js/showstring.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
```

and then in your JS:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById(wElement);
var JavaScriptCode = document.createElement("script");
JavaScriptCode.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
JavaScriptCode.setAttribute("src", 'http://batpigandme.com/js/data2.js');
myElement.appendChild(JavaScriptCode);
```